# Working around pyopencl array offset limitation

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

Is there a way to work around the limitation in PyOpenCL whereby:

```
array.data
```

fails with

> pyopencl.array.ArrayHasOffsetError: The operation you are attempting does not yet support arrays that start at an offset from the beginning of their buffer.

I tried:

```
a.base_data[a.offset: a.offset + a.nbytes]
```

This seems to work sometimes, but other times I get:

> pyopencl.LogicError: clCreateSubBuffer failed: invalid value

Answer (score 1):

[`clcreateSubBuffer`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateSubBuffer.html) needs to have the offset (or in this case it is called the `origin`) that is aligned, and the `size` + `origin` to fall within the limits of the buffer.

> CL_INVALID_VALUE is returned in errcode_ret if the region specified by
>   (origin, size) is out of bounds in buffer.
>
> CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET is returned in errcode_ret if there
>   are no devices in context associated with buffer for which the origin
>   value is aligned to the CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN value.

For the particular error you are seeing it looks like either your program or pyopencl is miscalculating the size of the array after the offset. Even if you fixed this you may still have problems if the original offset is not aligned to `CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN`.

Having said that NVIDIA seems to break from spec and allow arbitrary offsets. So your mileage may vary depending on the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, I did check to make sure that `0 <= a.offset < a.offset + a.nbytes <= a.base_data + a.size`, so I don't think that's it…  Could it be a problem unique to PyOpenCL?

Comment: @NeilG perhaps. There are other instances where the same error may be returned. I don't want to speculate further without looking at pyopencl code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to get a buffer that marks the start of the array data, to pass to a kernel, you don't have to worry about the size. Here's a function that gets a size-1 buffer that points to the start of the offset data:

```
def data_ptr(array):
    if array.offset:
        return array.base_data.get_sub_region(array.offset, 1)
    else:
        return array.data
```

You can use this to pass to a kernel, if you need a pointer to the start of the offset data. Here's an example, where I want to set a sub-region `clV` of array `clA` to the value 3. I use `data_ptr` to get a pointer to the start of `clV`'s data.

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

m, n = 5, 5
A = np.random.uniform(size=(m, n)).astype(np.float32)
clA = cl.array.Array(queue, A.shape, A.dtype)
clA.set(A)

clV = clA[1::2, 1::2]

def data(array):
    if array.offset:
        return array.base_data.get_sub_region(array.offset, 1)
    else:
        return array.data

source = """
__kernel void fn(long si, long sj, __global float *Y)
{
    const int i = get_global_id(0);
    const int j = get_global_id(1);
    Y[i*si + j*sj] = 3;
}
"""
kernel = cl.Program(ctx, source).build().fn
gsize = clV.shape
lsize = None

estrides = np.array(clV.strides) / clV.dtype.itemsize
kernel(queue, gsize, lsize, estrides[0], estrides[1], data_ptr(clV))

print(clA.get())
```

Comment: I see, you're passing the pointers to the opencl program and having it do the offset?  That works I guess, but it's definitely not ideal.

Comment: No, the offset is done before the program (i.e. it's not inside the kernel).

Comment: You're sending in the indices into the array as parameters to the program, aren't you?